Identify points lying on transects from a spatial dataframe in R
I have survey data, with recordings every 1 NM along parallel transects perpendicular to the coast. For each record I have information such as latitude and longitude, speed, bearing. Along the transects the speed is around 10 knots. I also have points along the inter-transects (where speed might be different, and bearing definitely is) and I have points outside the transects if a trawl was carried out.
What I would like to do is grouping all the points belonging to the same transects (e.g. see figure):

This was done simply using a distance between points of 1 NM and as you can see in the figure, this does not really work because whenever there is an inter-transect (like transect nr 5), this will be grouped together with the transect itself. Also, in transect 13, since the distance for some reason is slightly larger then 1 NM between 2 subsequent records, the points are separated into 2 transects (you can see the slightly different color).
Dataframe example shown here:
 |year  |datetime             |xkm   |ykm  |logdiff |time_diff |distance |bearing |speed |
 |<dbl> |<dttm>               |<dbl> |<dbl>|   <dbl>| <drtn>   |    <dbl>|   <dbl>| <dbl>|
 |------|----------           |------|-----|--------|------  --|---------|--------|------|
 |2023  |2023-09-26 15:03:00  |221.  |1606.|       1| 360 secs |        1|   -1.58|    10|
 |2023  |2023-09-26 15:08:00  |223.  |1606.|       1| 300 secs |        1|   -1.58|    12|
 |2023  |2023-09-26 15:14:00  |225.  |1606.|       1| 360 secs |        1|   -1.58|    10|
 |2023  |2023-09-26 15:19:00  |227.  |1606.|       1| 300 secs |        1|   -1.58|    12|
 |2023  |2023-09-26 15:25:00  |229.  |1606.|       1| 360 secs |        1|   -1.84|    10|
 |2023  |2023-09-26 15:30:00  |231.  |1606.|       1| 300 secs |        1|   -1.85|    12|
 |2023  |2023-09-26 15:36:00  |233.  |1606.|       1| 360 secs |        1|   -1.58|    10|
 |2023  |2023-09-26 15:41:00  |234.  |1605.|       1| 300 secs |        1|   -1.85|    12|
 |2023  |2023-09-26 15:47:00  |236.  |1605.|       1| 360 secs |        1|   -1.58|    10|
 |2023  |2023-09-26 15:52:00  |238.  |1605.|       1| 300 secs |        1|   -1.58|    12|

What could be the best approach to tackle that in R? I thought about some unsupervised machine learning algorithm, like clustering using dbscan, but I'm not sure I'm using it properly. Beside distance between points, I would like to use other parameters to classify whether a point belongs to a transect or not (such as bearing and speed for example).
My attempt:
# Prepare data for clustering
clustering_data <- df %>% select(year, speed, bearing, xkm, ykm)

dput(clustering_data) 

# dput output
structure(list(year = c(2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023), datetime = c(45195.6270833333, 45195.6305555556, 
45195.6347222222, 45195.6381944444, 45195.6423611111, 45195.6458333333, 
45195.65, 45195.6534722222, 45195.6576388889, 45195.6611111111
), xkm = c(221, 223, 225, 227, 229, 231, 233, 234, 236, 238), 
    ykm = c(1606, 1606, 1606, 1606, 1606, 1606, 1606, 1605, 1605, 
    1605), logdiff = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), time_diff = c(" 360 secs ", 
    " 300 secs ", " 360 secs ", " 300 secs ", " 360 secs ", " 300 secs ", 
    " 360 secs ", " 300 secs ", " 360 secs ", " 300 secs "), 
    distance = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), bearing = c(-1.58, 
    -1.58, -1.58, -1.58, -1.84, -1.85, -1.58, -1.85, -1.58, -1.58
    ), speed = c(10, 12, 10, 12, 10, 12, 10, 12, 10, 12)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

# Apply DBSCAN clustering
set.seed(123)
db <- dbscan(clustering_data, eps = 1.8, minPts = 5)


Any suggestion?

Unless the transects were all done simultaneously, it might be best to cluster them by timestamp. Also, if you have locations, speeds, bearings and timestamps, perhaps you can estimate the next point for each point, and find the closest match.

Hard to come up with a definitive answer without your full dataset. Run dput(clustering_data) and add the result to a codeblock in your question. The result will look something like structure(list(...)). Also, will you need a generalisable solution, or is the only data you need to process?

@LTyrone I've added the dput output as you requested. I have several years to process, but they all look very similar.

Also, what coordinate system are your lat/lon values in? They look like they are from a PCS?

And apologies, what I need is the full data for an entire year, so a dput() that contains all transects for 2023 for instance. This is needed in order to develop a way to determine the beginning and end of each transect.
